# Facebook like button - like content

Tags: facebook, xhtml, facebook-like

I got my facebook like button generated, and prepared it so user is able to like each post on my forum. The `href` attribute is set to the thread and certain post url, but when I click the like button, facebook is getting the logo, and the title of my forum for the liked post, instead I would rather want an user avatar and the post title to be posted.

Here I have pointed the element I would like to change, because it doesn't fit the post informations, but the whole page informations.

[image]

Are there any possibilities to change those?

Answer (score 1):

Adding these tags should fix your problem:

http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-meta-tags

Comment: I have added these tags, but its not working does it works with the `HTML5` and `XFBML`? Because I'm using the HTML5 like button version.